# Getcomponent(), GameObject, and Component issues

Tags: c#, unity

I have been trying for over 2 hours now to get over these problems :

1. I have 2 GameObjects in my hierarchy, but I do not have them anywhere in any script. I would very much like to add those 2 objects into a script of mine. I used

   GameObject thing1 = new GameObject("name of object");

but unfortunately this didn't work, gave me errors about how I can only create objects from main script? I pasted my code into game.cs, and added the game.cs script to the 2 objects I want, but I get the exact same errors.

2. So the reason for this problem is that I need to actually add those 2 objects in my lines of code, so I can use GetComponent(); to be able to modify the enabled status of my script. So the other problem here, is that when I use GetComponent on the 2 objects, I get a nullreference exception. I am very sure that I added the script to both the objects, and I'm pretty sure I didn't mistype them, so can anyone give me a hand please?

Comment: GetComponent returns a component from whatever GameObject your script is attached to... It does not find a GameObject in the scene. I don't really understand your question but maybe you should check out a few basic tutorials for unity

Comment: Yes, the syntax is mygameobject.GetComponent<componenttype>(); So I used the GameObject default constructor to try and get the objects I want into my scripts. That didn't work. I tried Find.GameObject("string"), it didn't work either. I tried everything I could have, and then I realised the constructor actually adds the GameObject to my script, the prblem is that GetComponent returns a null when I use GetComponent on the desired Game Object, with the type of the script I used.

Comment: @Savlon he wants to find a GameObject in the scene... as you said it yourself

Comment: @jhocking I already used that function. I apologize if I express myself in several lines, but I explained my problem as much as possible in my post. Kindly refrain from giving advice that isn't useful to the conversation.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Kindly refrain from being a jerk to people who are trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 2 GameObjects in my hierarchy, but I do not have them anywhere
>   in any script. I would very much like to add those 2 objects into a
>   script of mine. I used
>
> ```
> GameObject thing1 = new GameObject("name of object");
> ```

That would create a *new* GameObject. If you want to get an object by name, you'll need to call

```
GameObject thing1 = GameObject.Find("name of object");
```

That will locate the first object by that name. However, if you have multiple objects named that then you're in trouble. It would be better to expose a `GameObject` field on the component you're writing and link the object in the editor. Just drag the object from the hierarchy into the field on your component in the inspector.

> So the reason for this problem is that I need to actually add those 2
>   objects in my lines of code, so I can use GetComponent(); to be able
>   to modify the enabled status of my script. So the other problem here,
>   is that when I use GetComponent on the 2 objects, I get a
>   nullreference exception. I am very sure that I added the script to
>   both the objects, and I'm pretty sure I didn't mistype them, so can
>   anyone give me a hand please?

If you're trying to get a *component* named "name of object", then that will return a null because there cannot be a component named such. As above you need to *Find* the *GameObject* with that name. Then, to access their components, you'll call

```
SomeComponent component = thing1.GetComponent<SomeComponent>();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's this function http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html

But this may not be the ideal approach in your situation; it's hard to tell. The more typical approach to referencing objects in code is to link them in the Editor. To do that, declare a variable for the object at the top of your code, and then that variable will appear in the Inspector. Now drag your object onto the Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
```

Believe you want to instantiate a game object. Create a prefab, assign it, and use this command. As far as making a new new object, just make an empty game object, from there you can instantiate all components/renderers/colliders and whatever else